# Change region in UI testing for each case

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

i am using `swift-snapshot-testing` library to do snapshot testing. It's important for me to do all the tests with different localization to check all the UIs when the text is changed.
For example, the UI testing scheme is set to run on German language and region, In some tests, I want to see the english version as well and I did that

```
class BackgroundViewFactoryTests: XCTestCase {
    
    override class func setUp() {
        SnapshotTesting.diffTool = "ksdiff"
    }
    
    func test_backgroundView_contact_eng() {

        
        continueAfterFailure = false

        XCUIApplication().launchArguments += ["-AppleLanguages", "(en)"]

        XCUIApplication().launchArguments += ["-AppleLocale", "en_UK"]

        XCUIApplication().launch()
        
        let view = BackgroundViewFactory()
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        assertSnapshot(matching: view, as: .image, record: false)
        
    }
}
```

But it's still not working and run on German language, could anyone give me hit?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snapshot tests should be agnostic to all Strings. You don’t want breaking tests if you change one translation.
Test the translation in a separate UnitTest.

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean I should do UI testing with the main language, but test all the localization in Unit testing?

Comment: So this is depending on your flow. Is this a project only you are working on? -> the approach is fine. If there’s a team: can you ensure every work environment has the same language? Otherwise the snapshot tests will fail. You need to inject fixed strings to make the tests fully agnostic.

Comment: No it's my project and no one work on that except me

Comment: German strings are notorious for breaking the ui with overflows. You want a breaking test if you broke the UI. OP is right to want snapshots in German if their German customers are valued.

Comment: You should test that with a fixed string. There’s no need that the string is in German.